# Match parent for width of ImageView in snackbar with custom view in Android is not working

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am using snackbar with custom view. My custom view has only child view. That is an image view. Showing custom view with snack bar is OK. But the problem is with the sizing the ImageView in the snack bar. I want to set it match parent for with. But width is not match to the width of snackbar.

This is my custom view layout for snack bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_ad_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I show snack bar in activity

```
 private void showSnackbarAd(View view,Ad ad)
    {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout)snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.snack_bar_ad,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)snackView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_ad_image);
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(ad.getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        layout.addView(snackView, 0);
        snackbar.show();
}
```

What I want is I want ImageView same width width snack bar. But my code is not working.

This is what I got.

[image]

How can I make that ImageView as the same width with Snackbar and fit in snackbar?

Comment: It seems you want to stretch the image right? Some images might look very ugly when you do that.

Comment: Yes. I want to stretch. It is ok. Suitable image will be uploaded from backend. Cause it is for ad. Please how can I get it?

Comment: not sure if it works but try setting the scaleType to fitXY and set a fixed height, as the height of the snackbar should always be 48 or 80dp anyway.
You can read more about scaleTypes here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Add `android:scaleType="fitXY" ` to the `ImageView` in the xml

Comment: I set firXY. But just give me the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following code,

```
private void showSnackbarAd(View view,Ad ad) {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout)snackbar.getView();

        layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);//set padding to 0

        TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.snack_bar_ad, layout);// use the parent ViewGroup instead of null
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)snackView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_ad_image);
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(ad.getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        //layout.addView(snackView, 0);
        snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: This code is giving me java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.

Comment: i just tried, it works perfect on my device, could u post the stack trace please

Comment: Can I see your xml layout please?

Comment: Oh ya. It is working. I forgot to comment this line //layout.addView(snackView, 0). Thanks so much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library. This is a wrapper for android default snackbar.
https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/CSnackBar

```
Snackbar.with(this,null)
    .type(Type.SUCCESS)
    .message("Profile updated successfully!")
    .duration(Duration.SHORT)
    .show();
```

or you can even use your own view,

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

Snackbar.with(this,null)
        .type(Type.UPDATE)
        .contentView(view, 76)
        .duration(Duration.SHORT)
        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify width in xml. So image will fit into that width.
match_parent attribute will not set width as no specific size is specified.

Use can also try the below code,

```
Picasso.with(image.getContext()).load(ad.getImageUrl()).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: ImageView completely disappears from snackbar when I used this one.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever use a custom view, always avoid using LinearLayout as root element. It screws things up sooooooo oooooooften.

For your problem, try to replace LinearLayout in the xml with RelativeLayout.